# unable to create and use a Singleton class in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a Singleton class to save some variable and use it from other class. But I am getting following error when I am trying to access it.

```
TypeError: Singleton.createInstance is not a function
at /Users/pankajsachdeva/Desktop/Pankaj/My Code/SmilaApp/SmilaApi/app.js:17:35
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/pankajsachdeva/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/pankajsachdeva/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/pankajsachdeva/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/pankajsachdeva/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/pankajsachdeva/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/pankajsachdeva/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:341:12)
at next (/Users/pankajsachdeva/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (/Users/pankajsachdeva/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/pankajsachdeva/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Following is my Singelton class:

```
var mySingleton = (function() {
    let instance;
    let message;
  
    function createInstance() {
      if (!instance) instance = { setMessage, getMessage };
      return instance;
    }
    function setMessage(newMessage) {
      message = newMessage;
    }
    function getMessage() {
      return message;
    }
  
    return { createInstance }
  })();
```

I am trying to use it in following class:

```
    const express = require('express')
const Singleton = require('./mySingleton');

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.post('/readyforunlock', (req, res) => {
    var firstInstance = Singleton.createInstance();
    firstInstance.setMessage("Message");
    console.log(firstInstance.getMessage());
    res.send(firstInstance.getMessage());
})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I am very new to Node.js and not able to figure out why is it not working. I am trying to set some variable in one api and access it from another api. I am trying to achieve this using Singleton. Also please let me know if this correct approach or there are better options.

Regards

Comment: Looks like you might not be exporting your object from `mySingleton.js`? `module.exports = mySingleton`.

Comment: @MarcSances: The OP is not using class syntax.

Comment: Note that while it's not really obvious, what the error message is telling you is that `Singleton` is `undefined`.

Comment: FWIW, there isn't really a reason to create "singletons" like this. You could just created an object directly and export that: `module.exports = {message: ''}`. Or you could export he getter/setter methods directly from the module.

Comment: Hi @FelixKling can you please give me an example? I am very new to Node.js.

Comment: An example for what?

Comment: You mentioned that I can create an object directly and export that. Please remember I want to share some values between different apis

Comment: I already showed how: `module.exports = {message: ''}`.

Comment: I tried module.exports = mySingleton and error was gone because it but I am still not able to get the values in other api. My objective is to set some data(String) in api A and get this in api B.

Comment: `require` is essentially a *singleton revealing module pattern*, as it exports a cached instance, your IIFE revealing module pattern code is not needed, you could just move it all out the IIFE and do `module.exports = {createInstance}` and will be the same code

Comment: What are api A and api B? Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: There are two different post apis, api(endpoint) A will submit some string value and api(endpoint) B will read/ validate that string submitted from api(endpoint) A. I don't want to use any database here as it is just a small string.